# clicking a button that calls a delegate method deletes item in plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

in a firstViewController I presentViewController:secondViewController which contains a picker view loaded from an array in a plist, in this secondViewController you can add an item to the plist and picker view, this works fine then when i dismiss secondViewController, the items added are still okay but when i click a save button in firstViewController, the items added gets removed from the plist and picker view

in firstView

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {

Notes *myNote = [[Notes alloc]init];
//Declare a note called "myNote" and insert the Title, Text and Date properties of the note
[myNote setTitle:self.navigationItem.title andText:noteField.text andDate:dateLabel.text andCategory:categoryString];
//calls the noteAdded method in HomeViewController
[self.delegate noteAdded:myNote];
//Pop the New Notes View off the stack
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

when this gets clicked, any items that were added to the array in secondView gets removed from plist and pickerView

if i comment out

```
 [self.delegate noteAdded:myNote];
```

then the item remains in the plist

sorry if this sounds confusing

Comment: Not enough information. Can you paste more code

Comment: Yeah there isn't enough information. So are you adding the items in the secondViewController and then actually saving them into the plist via the "Save" button in firstViewController? What is the object and its respective implementation of the delegate noteAdded: ?

Comment: Hi, sorry, some of the code is really long, is there a particular bit you would like to see? to save posting uneceserry bits of code

Answer (score 0):

can you paste the code here so that we can figure it out. i Guess you are missing a little/small one in your code.